# How to cast ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable>> to Comparable?

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I want to add y to the x:

```
x.put("y", (Comparable) y);
```

y is defined as:

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable>> y = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable>>();
```

Output example of

> y =[{c=32,a=1, b=2 }, {c=33,a=4, b=5 }]

x is defined as:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable> x = new LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable>();
```

I am getting this error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable where i am trying to : x.put("y", (Comparable) y); and if I remove the comparable it shows that error exist in the eclipse.
Any suggestion?

/Elham

Comment: `ArrayList` do not implement `Comparable`

Comment: Also `Comparable` should usually be typed as well (to define what it can be compared with).

Comment: You are trying to assign a type of ArrayList to Comparable.That would not be possible. What exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want, you can create a class likes so

```
private static class CompArrayList extends ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Comparable>> implements Comparable
{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

define whatever you want in the `compareTo()` method and define y using this class

```
CompArrayList y = new CompArrayList ()
```

now y is `Comparable` and you can add it to your map

Answer (score 0):

Well, Thanks for your answers. This problem is solved by replacing x and y with the following:
ArrayList> y = new ArrayList<>(); 
Map x = new HashMap<>();

And then just use: x.put("y", y);